# Check if a gameObject will overlap before instantiation. [UNITY 2D]

Tags: unity-game-engine, overlap, gameobject, collider

I want to check if the my Prefeb Overlaps with a gameObject before I instantiate it. Note that the Prefabs vary in size and form.

I have tried way to many things and Googled a lot of stuff, but I can't get it to work. I even sinned by asking ChatGPT (it didnt yield any good results because of course it didnt). Could anyone provie me with a few code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Physics.Overlap functions, assuming that the colliders on your prefab object are more simple in nature.

For example:

```
public bool TestOverLapCircle(Vector2 point, CircleCollider2D prefabCollider)
{
    //get the overlap colliders with the radius of the CircleCollider multiplied by the scale
    Collider2D hitCollider = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(point, prefabCollider.radius * prefabCollider.transform.lossyScale.x);

    return hitCollider != null;
}
```

Comment: Editted to add 2D example